# Performance Benchmarks for Kafka KTables

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-database, ksqldb

I was able to find a few blog posts on benchmarks for Kafka messaging (throughout, latency).

Does anyone have references to benchmarks for queries/joins on KTables or GlobalKTables, as compared to other alternatives such as distributed databases?